# Connection problem after transfer magento 2.1 to new server.?

Tags: magento

I have migrated my magento website from one server to another, I have changed base url for secure and non secure to new domain, also changed database credentials in env file. but still i am getting error of PDO exception regard databse connection on exception log.

Note: I have enabled error log in index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error details?
*(keep sensible data out of it)*

As far as I usually encounter, errors like these are related to file permissions. Especially after migrating. Kindly check your files & folders permissions.

Of course the above is assuming the new server meets the system requirements (PHP version, PHP extensions and Mysql versions).

Here are the Magento System Requirements for v2.1.x: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Here is some info about permissions:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

And if you happen to use SELinux check this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/security.html